# UITextField is not editable, has only Touch Events, no Editing Events

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have a UITextField above a Google Maps View (GMSView). When I tap on the Textfield it does not become the first responder, neither do any of the delegate or action events work (Delegate Event like textFieldShouldBeginEditing and Action Events like .allEditingEvents).

The only way the Textfield is becoming the first responder is by hardcoding it in with

```
tf.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But when I tap on it nothing happens.

The Action Touch events like .touchUpInside etc. do work normally on the TextField, so I know the frame is ok.

I am creating and adding the TextView like this:

```
tf = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 300, height: 50))
tf.backgroundColor = .white
tf.placeholder = "sdfdsf"
tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapped), for: .touchUpInside)

self.mapView.addSubview(tf)

tf.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
tf.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
tf.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
tf.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

If you have any idea why this happens (or in this case does not happen) please leave a comment or an answer. I have worked on this for over 2 days straight now.

> UPDATE:
>
> I actually added the textfield to the Mapview itself. The Mapview
>   kinda does something strange with the layering of the view and messes
>   up the view of the TextView.
>
> The solution was to add the TextView to the main view and not to the
>   MapView subview.
>
> So it's (from back to front layer):
>
> ViewController
>
> (Main) View
>
> ```
>        Google Maps view
>        View
>           TextField
> ```
>
> This works

Comment: "neither do any of the delegate or action events work " - where did you set the delegate for the textfield ?

Comment: Hmmm... `UITextField` should not send a `.touchUpInside` event. Are you certain there is not a transparent element covering the text field that is acting on the touch event?

Comment: You can try to bring up the Xcode UI layer debugger tool to see if there is anything above the UITextField element https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: Do not answer by editing the question. Answer by adding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
self.mapView.bringSubviewToFront(tf) // Add this line below "self.mapView.addSubview(tf)"
This will ensure that the tf(TextField is on Top and Tappable)

Answer (score 0):

Did you assigne delegate to text field like :-
tf. delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to bring a subview to the front, you can use:

```swift
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tf)
```